# Homebrew, -bash: qemu: command not found OSX El Capitan

Tags: bash, terminal, path, homebrew, qemu

I'm trying to install qemu on my mac. I used Homebrew, and it seems like it has been successfully installed.

```
==> Installing qemu
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/qemu-2.6.0.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring qemu-2.6.0.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/qemu/2.6.0: 123 files, 127.4M
```

But when I try to use it I have:

```
-bash: qemu: command not found
```

The output of `ls /usr/local/Cellar/qemu/2.6.0/bin` is:

```
| ∮ -> ls /usr/local/Cellar/qemu/2.6.0/bin
ivshmem-client          qemu-system-aarch64     qemu-system-lm32        qemu-system-mips64      qemu-system-ppc         qemu-system-sh4eb       qemu-system-x86_64
ivshmem-server          qemu-system-alpha       qemu-system-m68k        qemu-system-mips64el        qemu-system-ppc64       qemu-system-sparc       qemu-system-xtensa
qemu-img            qemu-system-arm         qemu-system-microblaze      qemu-system-mipsel      qemu-system-ppcemb      qemu-system-sparc64     qemu-system-xtensaeb
qemu-io             qemu-system-cris        qemu-system-microblazeel    qemu-system-moxie       qemu-system-s390x       qemu-system-tricore
qemu-nbd            qemu-system-i386        qemu-system-mips        qemu-system-or32        qemu-system-sh4         qemu-system-unicore32
```

I now now that the problem is that the qemu file is missing. I still wonder why and how to fix it

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Erm... QEMU doesn't have any binary called `qemu`. Instead, you may use any `qemu-system-xxxx` binary to virtualize that system.

The documentation (when to use each system and stuff) is available at: http://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation

So, the formulaes names don't necessarily match the binary names. I suppose you know that, but I mention it just in case.

Feel free to keep sharing any problem you have with us!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to install it using `brew install qemu`?

I did that and got the same error. What I did instead was `sudo port install qemu` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on the answer of Lutarisco: to check if it's correctly installed:

```
$ qemu-system-arm --version
QEMU emulator version 4.0.0
Copyright (c) 2003-2019 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers
```